# Spring Boot + Azure AD Integration + oAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to implement Azure AD in my application, So prepared on POC(proof of concept) for the same.

I followed Some links and prepared some examples in Maven and Gradle both.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnzlN1zrcrI&t=300s

https://github.com/jeetmp3/tutorials/tree/master/azure-oauth2-demo

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

But still, examples are not working.

I used

- Spring Boot.
- Maven/Gradle.
- Spring Security.

On my local, it causes an error for redirect URL and SSL certificate because on Configuration we required HTTPS URL. So I deployed it on my server where all SSL certificate configuration is already done but after deployment, it causes an error.

[image]

Please suggest me a better latest example of the same, So I can implement the same and complete our things.

Comment: Looks like not to be an AAD issue. Please add more related tags about your server or configuration.